# Sitemap in google search result

Tags: sitemap

I am running this small service site [Bookkeeping Bots](http://www.bookkeepingBots.com)

How do I get the sitemap into the google search result? I tried to submit sitemap.xml to google webmaster. The submission is correct, but still no sitemap displayed in research result.

Please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The sitelinks are displayed automatically, only if the google search engine thinks they will be useful to the users.The link below will help you understand.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334